# Upload file using ajax request always fails

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, octobercms

I'm using [OctoberCMS](https://octobercms.com/) that implements [Laravel](http://laravel.com).

OctoberCMS have one AJAX framework based on jQuery AJAX.

> The `request()` method can be used with any element that is inside a form, or on a form element. When the method is used with an element inside a form, it is forwarded to the form.
>
> he `request()` method has a single required parameter - the AJAX handler
>   name. Example:
>
> `<form onsubmit="$(this).request('onProcess'); return false;">`
>
> The second attribute of the request() method is the options object. You can use **any option and method compatible with the jQuery
>   AJAX function**.
>   [See more](https://octobercms.com/docs/cms/ajax#javascript-api).

Good, i'm trying to send form data including one file (of course my form have `enctype="multipart/form-data"`). So, `request()` method look like this:

```
var 
   myForm = document.querySelector('#myForm'),

myForm.addEventListener('submit', function ( event ) {
  event.preventDefault();
  myFormData = new FormData( this );
  $( this ).request( 'onHandler', {
    data: myFormData,
    contentType: false,
    // this would make work
    proccessData: false,
    success: function ( response ) {
      // do something
    }, 
    error: function ( jqXHR ) {
      // do something    
    },
    complete: function () {
      // do something
    }
  });
});
```

When try submit the form i always have this log: 
**Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation**

Comment: try using $( myForm ).request( 'onHandler', [{ and close }]; instead of {, };

Comment: an object is the correct thing to pass as data though

Comment: @IlanHasanov this not work for me